# How to drive switch / spin buttons to toggle content displayed with Javascript

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

I'm trying to build a control where the user disposes of left and right buttons in order to change the displayed content of an inline . I've put the html part here: http://jsfiddle.net/Argoron/E5MsU/
The idea is that, when the user clicks the left or right button, the content displayed cycles through the list of available

s, displaying one at a time. The number and content of the list items will be dynamic.

I'm not sure how to tackle the javascipt part though. Can someone please point me in the right direction ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be a start.

You will need to do a check to see if you are at the start or the end of the list but hopefully you'll understand. Let me know if you have any problems

http://jsfiddle.net/leereichardt/E5MsU/1/